# What IDE / Editor do you use for Ruby on Windows?

Tags: windows, ruby, ide, editor

The SciTE editor comes with the Ruby installer, and it's just a generic code editor. I installed FreeRIDE but it seems a little buggy; it actually just crashed on me for no reason. :(

So my question is...

What IDE / Editor do you use for Ruby on Windows? What are the best editors out there?

Comment: Check this question: [Best Editor for Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59968/best-editor-for-ruby)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best editor or IDE for Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59968/best-editor-or-ide-for-ruby)

Comment: I can't see why this was closed. There might not be a canonical answer, but it is certainly a valid question in the context of "software tools commonly used by programmers", and it can certainly be answered with "[supporting] facts, references, or specific expertise". The "soliciting debates" or "engendering arguments or extended discussion" is a risk any answer on any question has, so is not a valid rationale for closing what is a good, on-topic question. Also, inconveniently, the two questions linked to above have been deleted. So Stackoverflow has been failed by its volunteer police, here.

Comment: +1. Though it does not have a definite right or wrong answer, it is a useful question. I have currently been asked to work on Ruby temporarily because the person maintaining the Ruby scripts of the system has left. I have no clue about what tools are the best for working with Ruby.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Netbeans IDE](http://www.netbeans.org/) is quite good.

Comment: Unfortunately in Netbeans 7.0 there's no longer ruby support, nor could I find where the community theoretically is building it: http://wiki.netbeans.org/RubySupport

Comment: Please consider adding your name to this petition to ask Oracle to re-include Ruby/Rails support in Netbeans: http://www.ipetitions.com/petition/re-include-ruby-support-in-netbeans/

Answer (score 5):

You can use either Eclipse with the Aptana Plugin and then install the Aptana RadRails plugin or you can use Aptana as a stand-alone application.

I like to use Eclipse with the Aptana plugins because Aptana seems to provide the best support for HTML, Javascript, and CSS that I've seen in an Eclipse plugin, and you still get the full benefit of using the core Eclipse application.

Answer (score 3):

E-Texteditor is great.

Answer (score 2):

[Farawla](http://www.getfarawla.com) code editor.

Disclaimer: I built it.

Answer (score 2):

i think [sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/) text editor is best for pure ruby files.

its lite and fast.

Comment: Sublime is not really free.  It will nag you to purchase.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) for a while now.  It has the basic features I want:

- Drag & Drop file opening.
- Detects changes to open files on the disk.
- Ruby syntax highlighting (works out of the box).

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse with RDT plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using Aptana Studio, it's quite good, with lots of features (even in the free version, you probably don't need Pro).

If you want something more minimalistic, there is E Text Editor, which supports TextMate bundles (not free, though).

Answer (score 1):

Your individual needs should dictate whether/when you use a full-featured IDE or a lighter weight code editor.

For lightweight tasks, I still prefer SciTE, tweaking the settings and functions to meet my own needs.

For larger projects I use the NetBeans Ruby IDE. I tried NetBeans a couple years ago and wasn't impressed. But they've come a long way since, especially with regards to Ruby and Rails. Nothing against Eclipse/Aptana; NetBeans just seems to fit me better.

Textmate is very popular on Mac OS, and E (not free, but inexpensive) is the closest thing to it on Windows, and supports TextMate bundles. It seems to have gained many fans.

Answer (score 1):

After seeing alot of screenshots from Mac-guys writing ruby-code in TextMate I went for the [E-TextEditor](http://www.e-texteditor.com/) and I'm very pleased with it.

At first I didn't find any option in the GUI for changing the default tab-size from 4 to 2 but today I found it down on the statusbar :)

Comment: I cudn't find that either. Got it thanks to you :-)

Answer (score 1):

[RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/index.html) is really great, even though it's $99 for commercial purposes (there are free flavors available) I think it's well worth the money.

It has great support for HAML/SASS, the most common revision control systems, console tools, templates, keyboard shortcuts, etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can find many IDE's for rails in windows such as

- [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org/)
- [Ruby in Steel](http://www.sapphiresteel.com/)
- [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/)
- [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/)

. For me NetBeans is the best IDE for rails developments but it may depend on your familiar IDE because earlier I have many experience with java developments in NetBeans. So if u have experience in NetBeans it could be the best but if you have experience with Visual Studio then Ruby in Steel would be good choice.

Answer (score 1):

[RedCar](http://redcareditor.com/). It's a Ruby editor. And it's free.

Comment: Bad editor.  I encountered three problems after using RedCar for a minute: it doesn't support opening files by dragging them into it.  It took about 5 seconds to open the first file I tried.  The Ctrl++ shortcut for increasing the font size is broken.

Answer (score 0):

[Ruby in Steel](http://www.sapphiresteel.com/), is integrated in visual studio, but not free of charge ($199)

Comment: They now offer a free "Personal Edition" of Ruby in Steel.

Answer (score 0):

Textmate from Macromates has a clone call e-texteditor

I totally recommend it, it is actually made by a friend of the textmate author

Comment: I forgot to add e-texteditor to my answer, but I have fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Another vote for E from http://www.e-texteditor.com

Answer (score 0):

Vim with the help of a few plugins ([Rails.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1567), [Project](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=69) and [Fuzzy File Finder Textmate](http://github.com/jamis/fuzzyfinder_textmate/tree/master)) Really makes for a good--and cross platform--editor.

If you like the plugins but can't take the keybindings there is always [Cream](http://cream.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

rored is really nice for rails apps on windows

Answer (score 0):

I use [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org) most of time, but occasionally [Intype](http://intype.info) fit my needs for some quick code editing.

Intype has a simple project manager, also support bundles and snippets.

Answer (score -5):

Go for Eclipse for everything. I tried Netbeans but it sucks! It doesn't even have a word-wrap feature! Can you believe that?

Comment: What is this obsession with word-wrap? I've seen several posts from people dumping an editor using lack of word-wrap as the primary reason. If you need to wrap your code, your lines are too long.

Comment: I can believe it. Word wrap is trashy.