# Ruby scripting on Windows

Tags: windows, ruby, scripting, odbc, exchange-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Ruby IDE do you prefer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16991/what-ruby-ide-do-you-prefer)

I'm making a **simple** script using ruby on a Windows 2003 Server.
My questions are:

- How can I connect to a database through ODBC?  I will be connecting to both **Sybase on Solaris** and **MSSQL Server**.
- How can I send emails through an Exchange Server 2003?

---

### Update

- What's the best simple IDE for Ruby scripting?  I currently use SciTE (which comes with Ruby)

Comment: This really is two separate questions, with the second one already answered many times on SO.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256365/what-ide-editor-do-you-use-for-ruby-on-windows
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59968/best-editor-for-ruby

Comment: Now this is really 3 questions. You should ask them seperately on SO.

Answer (score 3):

There is an ODBC package for the [Ruby DBI module](http://ruby-dbi.rubyforge.org/) available, or you can try to use the [ODBC binding for Ruby](http://www.ch-werner.de/rubyodbc/), which also includes a Win32 binary.

Here an example that uses RDI (stolen from [here](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/64065)):

```
require 'DBI'

# make an ODBC connection
conn = DBI.connect('DBI:ODBC:datasource','your_username','your_password')

# returns a list of the table names from your database
conn.tables

# returns an array with the resultset from your query
rs = conn.select_all('SELECT * FROM TheTable')
```

*(ODBC datasources can be defined using the ODBC Administrator available via Control Panel/Administrative Tools.)*

For e-mailing I would suggest you simply use the [standard mailing capabilities](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/smtp/rdoc/index.html) of Ruby and connect to your Exchange Server through SMTP.

I cannot recommend you a Ruby IDE, though, as I do my text-editing with VIM. :-) Other people might be able to give you a hint on that.

Answer (score 1):

For a Ruby IDE, try NetBeans.

Comment: NetBeans is one of the best IDEs I've ever used for any language, hands down.  Its Ruby support is spectacular.

Comment: I use NetBeans when I must use Windows or Linux. I use TextMate on my Mac. I don't need IDE support when I have a nice tool like that :)

Answer (score 1):

For simple but powerful use [ado and ruby on windows](http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.com/2007/03/ruby-ado-and-sqlserver.html).This is a really good example.

Answer (score 1):

Be warned that the ODBC drivers included with the One-Click Installer for Ruby don't seem to be Unicode aware. (Accessing a SQL Server database from Unix, I used FreeTDS to convert UTF-16 to UTF-8 prior to getting it from UnixODBC.) I haven't been able to make a similar conversion in Windows.